# Bigquery partition not being used while deleting data

Tags: google-bigquery

Our project is being charged a high cost. Looks like such commands are not using the partition. Is there a way in bigquery to force the query to become partition aware based on the results for a subquery ?

The following query currently is processing TBs of data.

```
    delete from tableName
    where QuoteDate >= cast((SELECT batch_date as start  from batch_table where  Batch_Status='Running') as timestamp)
```

*Processes 1TB of data.*

Ideally this should only process hundred MB of data.

```
delete from TableName
    where
        QuoteDate >= '2018-11-01'
```

*Processes ~100MB*

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables#pruning_limiting_partitions):

> Complex queries that require the evaluation of multiple stages of a query in order to resolve the predicate (such as inner queries or subqueries) will not prune partitions from the query.

...

> The following query does not prune partitions (note the use of a subquery):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.name,
  t2.category
FROM
  table1 t1
INNER JOIN
  table2 t2
ON
  t1.id_field = t2.field2
WHERE
  t1.ts = (SELECT timestamp from table3 where key = 2)
```

For the time being, you need to evaluate the queries that you have provided separately.

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) (Beta now), there is a way to reduce the cost.

Basically, a scripting variable is defined to capture the dynamic part of a subquery. Then in subsequent query, scripting variable is used as a filter to prune the partitions to be scanned.

```sql
DECLARE date_filter DATETIME 
  DEFAULT (SELECT batch_date from batch_table where  Batch_Status='Running');

delete from tableName
where QuoteDate >= date_filter;
```